# In Granita, Umberto Eco's short pastiche of Nabokov's Lolita, which words does he use in Italian to substitute 'nymphet'?

Tags: translation

In 1959, Umberto Eco published a short pastiche of Nabokov's novel *Lolita*. An English [translation](https://thefloatinglibrary.com/2008/08/24/granita/) named "Granita" was published in the anthology *Misreadings* in 1994.

In this pastiche, a certain Umberto Umberto (Umberto being the Italian version of Humbert as well as the author's given name) writes about his tempestuous flight through Piedmont with the geriatric Granita, the object of his desires and recipient of his sexual attention.

In the English translation, the word 'nymphets' from Nabokov's work is substituted with 'nornettes'.

Am I correct in surmising that this is a word-play based on the Italian *nonna* (grandmother)?

Which word did Eco use in the Italian original?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Italian original is titled *Nonita* and can be found in this [post](https://ultimacrociata.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/chi-ha-paura-di-vladimir-nabokov/).

You can see that the word used in the original that has been translated into English as "nornettes" is *parchette*:

> Per designare costoro, sconosciute ai più, dimenticate dalla indifferenza lubrica degli abituali usagers di friulane sode e venticinquenni, adoprerò, lettore, oppresso anche in questo dai rigurgiti di un’impetuosa sapienza che mi atterrisce ogni gesto di innocenza che mai tenti – un termine che non dispero esatto: *parchette*.

I don't perceive in the term you mention any connection with the word "nonna", but with [Parcae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcae), that in Italian are called [*Parche*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parche/): *parchette* would be some kind of diminutive of *Parche*. It seems that, for some reason, the translator to English has decided to refer to the [Norns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norns) when using "nornettes".

As @DaG has said in his comment, Nobokov's "nymphets" are a diminutive form of nymphs, Roman mythological figures associated with youth, whereas Parcae (and also Norns in Germanic mythology) are associated with old age.

That said, the title *Nonita* seems to me a clear reference to the Italian word *nonna* that, as I've learned reading Primo Levi's short stories, is pronounced *nona* in Piedmont.

Comment: “_parchette_ would be some kind of diminutive of _Parche_”: exactly, just like _ninfetta_ / “nymphet” is a diminutive form of _ninfa_ / “nymph”, a different Roman mythological figure, which is associated with youth, just like the Parcae are associated with old age. For the record, the original text by Eco was part of _Diario minimo_, a collection of columns by Eco published in the magazine _Il Verri_, featuring short essays and divertissements.

Comment: "Nonita" is a clever find for the title; I think I like it even better than the English "Granita". Thanks for clearing up the mythologically derived terms! Eco's playful short story is a delight to read for anyone who's read _Lolita_.